# Windows 7 and ocx installation

Tags: windows-7

I am having one application which runs on XP very well. What it does is it downloads some files from server and register one ocx object. In XP after installing I am able to see the entry in the RegEdit with name of that ocx component. But same thing I tried on the Windows 7 and its not registering that ocx component. I having same access rights as XP on windows 7. 
I am unable to find any entry in RegEdit. I tried installing it manually by Running Command Prompt As Administrator then it installs successfully..

How can I do it automaticallly as it works in XP? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Remember that Windows Vista and above has Registry Virtualization - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx - which is part of the security changes in these OSes. Since you can complete the action as an administrator this surely means that it's security issue? Your program as current need to run with Elevated Security Permissions.

Comment: is it means i am having diferent permissions on xp and windows 7?

Comment: Yes you need to do a whole load of reading on User Access Control and other Vista + security changes. The OSs have lots of security differences.

Comment: Thanks for Preet. Can you please add your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I dont have the Admin Rights on the XP also but still I am able to register component.